# NUnit GUI Runner Multiple Configuration Files

Tags: nunit

I created a test project using a web.config file by renaming it to same name as the project, copying it to the bin folder and setting the Configuration File Name of the NUnit GUI runner to the name of my config file. Now I want to add more assemblies to this project but the problem here is each assembly has it's own web.config file.

How can I set the configuration files for the assemblies because I need to get my connection strings from these config files and considering when loading multiple assemblies they need to be in the same directory

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I feel that using config files for NUnit tests is a no-no (it's an integration test, in that case, I assume), there are various approaches you can try:

- Put all your different connection strings under web.config in the connectionstrings section, with different keys. Access them via the System.Configuration classes.
- For each project or DLL you can add an app.config file where you can store assembly specific information. This will be renamed as ProjectName.dll.config once compiled. Again you can access the contents of this file using System.Configuration
- Create a new assembly that simply loads all these connection strings from a single file. And then access this assembly

If you are loading different web applications into the same directory (as you're saying you're accessing web.config files -- which means web applications) then you're making your life difficult. Each application has to have their own folder and virtual directory, and a web.config specific to only that application.

Comment: I followed the third approach. :D .. Thanks